# VS Test Runner is slow on Visual Studio Online

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, build, azure-devops

I am using **Visual Studio Online** for **building** and **testing** my application.

Executing my tests is really slow with Visual Studio Online....
In the diagnostics log of my Build I can see that **VS Test Runner** take **22 minutes in the cloud** when it takes **less than 1 minutes on my computer** (I have +/- 500 NUnit tests).

Anyone has experienced the same issue?

Update : 99% of testing time is taken by 3 tests.
Two of them have an exception. One of them pass.

Comment: I've not tried running tests in online. Sorry to say this 3 minutes is not less time for 500 tests, I guess you're doing something wrong in your unit tests.

Comment: I have the same issue, however I don't know why that's happing.

Comment: @Sriram Sakthivel: my tests are correct.

Comment: Do any of your tests cross application boundaries? (e.g., accessing database, file system, etc.)

Comment: @Lilshieste: No. But I have some warnings: System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.

Comment: Can you see from your test results (TRX file) which tests are taking the time (you might need to add the column to see). Is it just one/two tests, or are they all slow?

Comment: @DaveShaw: I have 3 tests that take 99% of the time. One has a NullRefException.Another on an AppDomainUnloadedEx. And the last one passed... Its really strange.

Comment: Might be worth changing the question to focus on those tests :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why VS TestRunner was taking so much time for processing our unit tests was :

> ```
> The [Ignore] attribute of NUnit was not taken into account by VS TestRunner in VSO.
> So we had some dirty Unit Tests that were executed against our will.
> ```